# SQL Query required where we should not used the group by and data count based on dep_id

Tags: group-by

Need your help in getting the SQL Query.
1. I have one table which is having following columns

```
Name         Null?    Type         
------------ -------- ------------ 
EMP_ID       NOT NULL NUMBER(2)    
DEP_ID                NUMBER(2)    
SALARY                NUMBER(14,3) 
NAME1                 VARCHAR2(50) 
NAME2                 VARCHAR2(50) 
JOINING_DATE          DATE
```

Now I want the result - COUNT(1) based on DEP_ID without using GROUP BY .

EXAMPLE :

```
select DEP_ID,COUNT(1) from unipartemp group by DEP_ID;
```

```
DEP_ID COUNT(1)
1       2
2       2
3       1
```

What is the Query where we should get the same result but we should not use group by ...

Please suggest .

Comment: writing in block letters wouldn't help others help you especially when there is no code formatting. you can use ctrl + k or backticks i.e. `` to format it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the result u r looking for is the count of the distinct dept_id. Try using the distinct(dept_id) to get the result.

Comment: No its giving all dep_id uniq values .. i need the output like below:DEP_ID COUNT(1)
1       2
2       2
3       1